# Wordpress Admin page on Ubuntu is hidden by the grey screen

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, screen, admin, hidden

I've just move all wordpress site from Windows server to Ubuntu server. The main site (http://example.com) show correctly, but the admin page (~/wp-admin) has problems.

I can see the left sidebar only (post, page, theme...), but the main frame where shows me the content of post to edit, lists my plugins,... now is hidden by the grey screen, and I can't  do anymore with it.

You can see the screenshot here: https://www.upsieutoc.com/image/DWnf (sorry I don't have enough repu for post photo directly), and sorry because my language (Vietnamese) in the screenshot.

Thanks for reading my post and hope you answer me ASAP

Comment: I've just tested with a new wordpress site, and the problem had gone. But I can't re-create all my existing site

Comment: I finally find out the resolution. After delete the plugin wp-super-cache, everything perfect. CLOSE